# Wine reduction sauce a little too rich

Tags: sauce, beef, wine

I made a wine reduction sauce using a great merlot and some low sodium broth (onions and fond too!). I started by making a roux and then reduced the sauce. It has great consistency and tastes great but I'm afraid its a little too rich. Is there a way to brighten it up? I was thinking red-wine vinegar but I'm not sure.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

Adding an acid is indeed the way to brighten a sauce.  You could go with vinegar (red wine, sherry, champagne, rice) depending on the ingredients in the sauce. Alternately, a squeeze of lemon is often used.  Start with a small amount...you can alays add more.